# Read input as a value in textfile

Tags: c#

So basically, I have a "product" text file with name, category number, price, stock, re-order level. I need a program to read the input as the category number, and if any item's stock in that category is lower than re-order level, then output that item. For example, if I input "3", then all of the items that have less stock than re-order level in category 3 will be output.
This is my current code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> product = LoadData();
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input != "#")
        {
            stuff(input, product);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void stuff(string input, List<Product> product)
    {
        int cat = int.Parse(input);
        foreach (var item in product)
        {
            cat = item.Category;
            if (item.Stock < item.Reorder)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }

    private static List<Product> LoadData()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/data/products.txt");
        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
        while (reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] br = line.Split(',');
            int category = int.Parse(br[1]);
            double price = double.Parse(br[2]);
            int stock = int.Parse(br[3]);
            int reorder = int.Parse(br[4]);
            Product products = new Product(br[0], category, price, stock, reorder);
            list.Add(products);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

The thing here is, it output nothing when I input. So I wonder if there is something wrong with this code?

Comment: You didn't ask any question here. Also what ever it is you need to give text file content format and Product class implementation also.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `if (item.Stock < item.Reoder)` be `if (item.Stock < cat)`?

Comment: Have you debugged it?  Does your LoadData() function actually load data or is it an empty list?  Are you sure that you are extracting the csv to the correct properties?

Comment: @Mephy : No, it will output if stock < re-order level, the cat is just the input to say which category we want to check

Comment: You're not using `cat` for anything in your very well-named `stuff` method.

Answer (score 0):

This should be changed:

```
while (reader.EndOfStream)
```

to this:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
```